# Memory padding issues using __declspec

Tags: c++, memory

based on MSDN the __declspec(align(x)) should add x bit padding after the member variables for example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    struct test
    {
        __declspec(align(32))char x;
          __declspec(align(32))int i;
          __declspec(align(32)) char j;
    };   
    cout << sizeof(test) << endl;//will print 96 which is correct
}
```

now consider the following case:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    struct test
    {
          char x;
          int i;
          char j;
    };   
    cout << sizeof(test) << endl;//will print 12
    //1 byte for x + 3 bytes padding + 4 bytes for i + 1 byte for j +3 bytes padding =12 
}
```

but if i change the code to this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    struct test
    {
          char x;
          int i;
          __declspec(align(1)) char j;
    };   
    cout << sizeof(test) << endl;//will print 12 again!!!!

}
```

why it is giving me 12 instead of 9! i am telling the compile that i don't want any padding after j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__declspec(align(1)) char j` doesn't do anything - a `char` requires no special alignment with or without the `__declspec`.

Imagine you later declare an array of `test`: `test arr[2];`. Here, both `arr[0].i` and `arr[1].i` must be aligned on the 4-byte boundary; that requires that `sizeof(arr[0])` be a multiple of 4. That's why there's padding at the end of the structure.

Comment: how can I tell the compiler not to put any padding at the end?